Запоминание входа в django
Как сохранить уникальные данные устройства, с которого пользователь авторизовался на сайте Django? IP-адрес одинаковый для всех устройств, которые подключены к одной сети, хотел бы узнать с какого конкретно устройства пришел запрос на сайт, чтобы сохранить его в базе и ассоциировать с аккаунтом телеграм, через который пользователь авторизовался на сайте.

про cookies вы что-нибудь слышали?

да, но хотелось бы узнать про реализацию этого через cookies, почитал на сайтах, не совсем понял как сохранять cookies в браузере клиента через джанго

не знаю, что вы почитали, но поиск выдает кучу результатов по запросу django cookies со вполне понятными инструкциями

А если пользователь сменит устройство?
